# How can I add folders to my template directory and have Twig find them?

Tags: 8, theming

I was listening to a Drupal Developer on youtube and one of the suggestions he has, is that when you go into a template folder, create some subdirectories for easier management, like this:

```
Templates
->Blocks
->Fields
 ->YourField.html.twig
->Nodes
```

So I want to do the same thing for my template folder, however when I do that, I get this error:

> Twig\Error\LoaderError: Template "modules/custom/task/templates/field--expire-date.html.twig" is not defined.

Now granted, I learned with Drupal that Twig + Theming Templates is different than Twig + Module Templates. I am using my own module.

Is there a way for me to tell Twig there is another subdirectory (Ex: Fields Folder), so it can find the code?

Comment: Clear/Flush all caches.

Comment: Once again for clarification. You are not in a theme, you are in a custom module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your "task" module you must have a task_theme function where you've defined your templates. In there you'll need to update with your new paths too. e.g.

This

```
'template' => "field--expire-date.html.twig"
```

becomes:

```
'template' => "fields/field--expire-date.html.twig"
```

Comment: Thanks a Million Sir! You get a "Your Awesome!" comment! ^_^